# "Русская папка" пользователя

Tags: c#, .net

следующая строчка кода возвращает путь, который содержит "кириллицу".

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

возвращает:

```
C:\Users\Иван\Documents
```

Есть ли способ получить строку, которая будет указывать на тот же путь, но при этом не содержать кириллицу?

нужно получить строку в ASCI или в ISO-8859-1

Comment: Любопытный вопрос из-за своей недосказанности. Попробуем наугад: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` подойдёт? (Если есть права залезть в чужого пользователя - не подойдёт, а если программа работает с текущим - то может и подойдёт). Отдельно любопытно, как будет выглядеть если пользователь воспользовался правом перенаправления папки в русскоязычную папку например в `c:\Мои документы`.

Comment: @AK, в проводнике  работает, вот в коде к сожалению не хочет

Comment: @Gardes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993561/c-sharp-open-file-path-starting-with-userprofile

Comment: @iluxa1810, это обратная ситуация, когда %USERNAME% заменяется ее значением.

Comment: а что мешает перекодировать в 866? https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp866.html

Comment: @iluxa1810, 866 поддерживает кириллицу?

Comment: кодовая страница 866 и есть кириллица в консоли :)

Comment: @Gardes ну вон проматай вниз мою ссылку. Там есть русские буквы.

Comment: @iluxa1810, нашел, но мне нужно именно либо в ASCI либо ISO-8859-1

Comment: ASCI, ISO-8859-1, cp866, cp1251 - все это восьмибитные кодировки, у них одинаковые номера указывают на разные символы соответствующих таблиц. Другими словами, это одно и тоже.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ. Вы можете создать алиас в виде мягкой ссылки.

Comment: ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) - с двумя «I»

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, зачем вам это нужно, но вы можете создать мягкую [ссылку](https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/hardlink-and-symlink-windows):

> mklink Создает символьную ссылку.
>
> MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Ссылка Назначение
>
> ```
>     /D          Создает символьную ссылку на каталог.
>                 По умолчанию создается символьная ссылка на файл.
>     /H          Создает жесткую связь вместо символьной ссылки.
>     /J          Создает соединение для каталога.
>     Ссылка      Указывает имя новой символьной ссылки.
>     Назначение  Указывает путь (относительный или абсолютный), на который ссылается
>                 новая ссылка.
> ```
>
> C:>mklink /D "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Update Cache" "d:\distr\Sql Server\Update Cache"
>
> Символическая ссылка создана для c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Update Cache <<===>> d:\distr\Sql
>   Server\Update Cache

на латинице, при переходе по которой вы будете попадать в тоже место, что и по кириллической ссылке.

Для файловой системы и программ это будет абсолютно незаметно.

Возможно, у вас цель заставить работать программу, которая не дружит с кириллицей в путях => это решит вашу проблему.

**UPD**

Еще есть вот [такой](https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/fsutil.html) вариант через создание короткого имени:

> fsutil file setshortname ”C:\Program Files” PROGRA~1 - присвоить папке
>   ”C:\Program Files” короткое имя PROGRA~1

Создается алиас.

Comment: Да, моя цель подружить стороннюю библиотеку с кириллицей, либо придется исключить кириллицу на корню

Comment: а можно пример как использовать это дело? Не совсем понятно.

Comment: @Gardes https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/hardlink-and-symlink-windows просто после /D написать путь к директории, где должен быть алиас, а вторым путем написать реальную директорию и в итоге будет создан файл в виде ярлыка.

Comment: Еще можно попробовать запустить программу через runAs и указать учетку не кириллическую. p.S А что либа забыла в папке юзера?

Comment: я сам хочу чтобы файлы которая создает программа хранились в папке юзера, не хотелось бы хранить их в общей папке документов

Comment: @Gardes ну... если вы кладете, то тогда это должен быть рабочий вариант, так как если бы либа вычисляла сама, то попадала бы на кирилическую папку.

Comment: @Gardes ну что помогло?

Comment: да, но мне нужен вариант без сторонних утилит, пока добавил в общие документы.

Comment: @Gardes ну так то это утилиты, которые есть на любом пк. Даже в линуксе это есть, но зовётся иначе.